# .NET 6 Swagger generates too many schemas - why?

Tags: swagger, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

[image]

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(
    options =>
    {
        options.UseOneOfForPolymorphism();
        // .....
    });
```

Environment

- ASP.NET Core 6
- Swagger v6.5.0

I don't need schemas about CLR. How can I remove (or filter) them?

Comment: Which framework are you using - Swashbuckle, NSwag, something different?

Comment: sorry my bad, i use Swashbuckle.AspNetCore v6.5.0

Comment: What do you want with the codes   options.UseOneOfForPolymorphism(); ? Why not just custom a filter and apply it ?Could you explain more details of your requirement?